# Creating custom SAML token

Tags: .net, wif, saml

I need to create SAML token with custom data.

There is a good looking example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355062%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#1) but it's not compiling....

Have anybody got smt to read about it of working sample?

Or is just adding new claims to Assertion collection?
Do i need to describe them in federationmetadata?
What other issues should i do?
Would be glad to see any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I remember there's some custom SAML token generation code in one of the ACS samples. That would be a good place to start. You can download it [here](http://acs.codeplex.com/releases/view/57595), look for the OAuth2CertificateSample, SelfSignedSaml2TokenGenerator.cs. The code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a SAML assertion signed with the given certificate.
/// </summary>
public static Saml2SecurityToken GetSamlAssertionSignedWithCertificate(String nameIdentifierClaim, byte[] certificateWithPrivateKeyRawBytes, string password)
{
    string acsUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://{0}.{1}", SamplesConfiguration.ServiceNamespace, SamplesConfiguration.AcsHostUrl);

    Saml2Assertion assertion = new Saml2Assertion(new Saml2NameIdentifier(nameIdentifierClaim));

    Saml2Conditions conditions = new Saml2Conditions();
    conditions.NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow;
    conditions.NotOnOrAfter = DateTime.MaxValue;
    conditions.AudienceRestrictions.Add(new Saml2AudienceRestriction(new Uri(acsUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
    assertion.Conditions = conditions;

    Saml2Subject subject = new Saml2Subject();
    subject.SubjectConfirmations.Add(new Saml2SubjectConfirmation(Saml2Constants.ConfirmationMethods.Bearer));
    subject.NameId = new Saml2NameIdentifier(nameIdentifierClaim);
    assertion.Subject = subject;

    X509SigningCredentials clientSigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(
            new X509Certificate2(certificateWithPrivateKeyRawBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable));

    assertion.SigningCredentials = clientSigningCredentials;

    return new Saml2SecurityToken(assertion);
}
```

Also, the authentication process doesn't require issued claims to be described in federation metadata. The claims published in federation metadata are only hints for the token consumer as to what they should expect to find in the issued token.

Comment: Just as I thought, the only problem I had in my code was forgetting to set the signingcredentials. Great Snippit. Much Love.

Comment: New ACS download location: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385