# Create SAML2 assertion without KeyInfo

Tags: .net, wif, saml-2.0

The WIF code example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895269/151212) creates a signed SAML2 assertion.

The eventual xml has the following structure (I've chopped out all the values because they're not important to this question):

```
<Assertion>
  <Issuer></Issuer>
  <Signature>
    <SignedInfo>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
  <Subject>
    <NameID></NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation/>
  </Subject>
  <Conditions/>
</Assertion>
```

But for a particular test scenario I need to create it without the `<KeyInfo>` element.

Is this possible with the WIF Saml2Assertion class? I have to provide the `SigningCredentials` but so far have not found a way to *just* sign but not include `<KeyInfo>` (force the recipient to already have the cert).

```
assertion.SigningCredentials = clientSigningCredentials;

return new Saml2SecurityToken(assertion);
```

Again, silly test scenario but it's something I want to simulate because I think this is supported by the standard.

Comment: In theory "keyInfo" is optional. But it would surprise me if there are implementations that can work without it. They would be inefficient (if not worse).